# How to bring two model fields under one report ID odoo 9 (REPORT)?

Tags: python, odoo-9

As of now, I am generating a report for the model (receive.orders) I want to get one field from (sale.order) "One2many" field.. how to get the field from two different model under one report.

Comment: what you have achieved so far, please input the code

Comment: Hi Pravitha, I have generated(achieved) report for the one model (receive.orders) in this (receive.orders) I want  to get the one field from (sale.order) that field is presented in "One2many" field of (sale.order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<t t-foreach='o.On2many_field_name' t-as='value'>
      <span t-field="value.field_name1"/>
</t>
```